# How to setup a Laravel app in a subdomain-directory in a shared host?

Tags: laravel, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to access my Laravel application through *a directory* in a subdomain in a shared host; as in `sub.domain.com/dir`. I want to be able to properly hit the app routes as `sub.domain.com/dir/posts`.

Thus, I've set the `APP_URL=https://sub.domain.com/dir/` in the `.env` file. It works through `sub.domain.com/dir/public`; but the *relatively-addressed media* are inaccessible; they are referenced as `sub.domain.com/path/to/asset`, while they should be `sub.domain.com/dir/path/to/asset`:

```
sub.domain.com/dir/path/to/asset        <---   accessable: Expected
sub.domain.com/path/to/asset            <--- inaccessable: What is given
```

In an attempt to drop the `/public` part, I've put the following code in an `.htaccess` file inside of `<docroot>/dir` directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /dir/public/$1 [L,QSA]
```

It seems to be effective on dropping the `/public` part (let me know if there are issues with that).

Here is the main issue: considering the `web.php` file to be like:

```
Route::get('/{num}', function ($num) { return "Number: $num"; })->where('num', '\d+');
Route::get('/{any}', function ($any) { return "Other: $any"; })->where('any', '.*');
```

Accessing `sub.domain.com/dir/123`, gets `Other: dir/123` instead of `Number: 123`: Laravel considers the `/dir/123` as the routing matter, while I want it to treat the `/123` as the routing matter. The same issue causes the assets to not to originate from `sub.domain.com/dir` but rather from the subdomain root: `sub.domain.com`, without the `/dir` suffix).

I want the `sub.domain.com/dir` to be considered as a whole (as if the `/dir` is part of the domain, in that the relatively-addressed media would be accessible); and what follows the `/dir` part, to be fed into Laravel app for routing and all the other stuff.

So, how should I setup my Laravel app in a subdomain-directory in shared host?

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines of code in your laravel root directory .htaccess file, which might be in your sub.domain.com/dir directory.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

that will solve your /public problem.
For the Media assets, did you used the asset URL helper function to link the media assets?

Comment: Thanks for the reply; as per the OP, I've already resolved the `/public` matter; the thing is, I want Laravel to treat the `sub.domain.com/dir` as a whole (the `/dir` to be somehow as part of the domain). Accessing `sub.domain.com/dir/123`, outputs `Other: dir/123`, while I want it to output: `Number: 123`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).